# I need to perform a Stemming operation in python ,without nltk . Using pipeline methods

Tags: pipeline, stemming

I have a list of words and a list of stem rules.
I need to stem the words that their sufixes are in the stem rules list.I got a hint from a friend that i can use pipeline methods

For example if i have :
stem=['less','ship','ing','les','ly','es','s']
text=['friends','friendly','keeping','friendship']

i should get :'friend','friend','keep',friend'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

rules = {'ness': '',
'ational': 'ate',
'ing': '',
'sses': 'ss'}

def stemx(inp:str):
for x in rules:
if inp[len(inp) - len(x):] == x:
return inp[0:len(inp) - len(x)] + rules[x]
return inp

print(stemx('singfds'))

Answer (score 1):

You can find and edit patterns using regular expressions (re package)

```py
import re

text = ['friends', 'friendly', 'keeping', 'friendship']
stems = [
    # next line finds patterns and remove them from the string.
    re.sub(r'less|ship|ing|les|ly|es|s', '', word) 
    for word in text
]

print(stems)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.